# Is there a way to generate tree view in SQL Server Report Builder?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[View my result set ScreenShot with tree structure or path like structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKKha.jpg)

I have a set of categories and sub-categories.
Requirement is to get the size of different categories and sub-categories on SQL Report Builder in the form of tree view.

What is the most possible way to display the report in tree view? and is it possible to display it in SQL Report Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Add a one group of your categorized field and check group properties>>advanced set document view as group name then add another group for subcategory and do the same procedure with set recursive parent=category field. Try this.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example so that it is easily understood.